# CkEditor5 insertContent Function not working

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to use insertContent method but getting some error.

Here is my implementation

```
<div id="editor">
    <p>This is the editor content.</p>
</div>
<button onclick="update()">update</button>

<script src="./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    var editorInstance;
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
        .then(editor => {
            editorInstance = editor;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

    function update() {
        editorInstance.model.insertContent("<p><b>Test</b> Content</p>")
    }
</script>
```

update method should update the editor source with given content, but I am getting an error

Error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.is is not a function
>       at xc.Nm (converters.js:777)
>       at xc.fire (emittermixin.js:209)
>       at xc. [as insertContent] (observablemixin.js:259)
>       at update (ck5.html:19)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ck5.html:4)

Can anyone please help in sorting out this issue?

Answer (score 4):

This error appears to be caused by trying to use the `insertContent` method to insert HTML - this method seems to expect a plain text string by default, although we can make it accept HTML with a few extra steps.

First of all, you'll need to grab the HTML Data Processor:

```
const htmlDP = editorInstance.data.processor;
```

Next you need to convert your HTML string into a viewFragment using the HTML Data Processor that we just obtained:

```
const viewFragment = htmlDP.toView("<p><b>Test</b> Content</p>");
```

Last of all, we need to convert the viewFragment to a modelFragment:

```
const modelFragment = editorInstance.data.toModel( viewFragment );
```

Now we can pass the modelFragment to the `insertContent` method:

```
editorInstance.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
```

This should remove the error and allow the mark-up string to be inserted into the editor

Comment: It trims or copy attributes to child elements. Not working as desired.

Comment: Tried inserting a `<span>` but it drops it and replaces it with a `<p>` and drops custom `class` attribute as well, waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

for those who are trying to implement it in React project,

using "setData" might be one of the considerable options.

```
const ChildComponent1 = ({ editorRef }) => (
  <CKEditor
   {...other props}
   onReady={(editor) => {
    editorRef.current = editor;
   }}
  />
)
```

---

```
const ChildComponent2 = ({ editorRef }) => {

  const insertTest = () => {
    const editorInstance = editorRef.current;
    if (editorInstance && typeof editorInstance.setData === 'function') {
      const contentToInsert = '<p>test</p>';
      const currentData = editorInstance.getData();
      const newData = currentData + contentToInsert;
      editorInstance.setData(newData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div css={{ padding: '4px 16px 6px' }} onClick={insertTest}>
      test
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

```
Const ParentComponent = () => {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent1 editorRef={editorRef} />
      <ChildComponent2 editorRef={editorRef} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me so I decided to use textarea field and setData function.
So in my case I was using a hidden textarea field instead of setting data directly in CKEditor.
Whenever it changes I get data from it and set in CKEditor like this:

```
document.querySelector('#textareaField').addEventListener('change', () => {
    const textareaFieldContent = document.querySelector('#textareaField').value;
    editorInstance.setData(textareaFieldContent);
});
```

and to trigger change event after putting data in textarea I used this code:

```
const changeEvent = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
document.querySelector('#textareaField').dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```